# Multiline heredoc with sudo in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, dockerfile, heredoc

We use our local repo in sources.list, and for 20.04 it required to add in `apt.conf.d`
`Acquire::https::local_repo.local_host.com::Verify-Peer "false";`

With Bash it works, as using,

```
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80ssl-exceptions > /dev/null <<'EOF'
Acquire::https::local_repo.local_host.com::Verify-Peer "false";
EOF
```

But I don't find a solution to do it for Dockerfile.
I've tried it with different escape character/new line and so on, but always unsuccessful.
For example,

```
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80ssl-exceptions > /dev/null <<'EOF' \
Acquire::https::local_repo.local_host.com::Verify-Peer "false"; \
EOF
```

Results - `/bin/sh: 1: EOF: not found`

To note that `cat` or `echo` is not an option, also adding those 3 line in a script is also not preferable.

Comment: Why are `cat` and `echo` not an option?

Comment: because `sudo` is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one line to append then I wouldn't use a heredoc. It's simpler to use `echo`:

```
RUN echo 'Acquire::https::local_repo.local_host.com::Verify-Peer "false";' | \
        sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80ssl-exceptions > /dev/null
```

Or `cat`:

```
RUN cat <<< 'Acquire::https::local_repo.local_host.com::Verify-Peer "false";' | \
        sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80ssl-exceptions > /dev/null
```

Or send the string directly to `sudo tee`:

```
RUN sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80ssl-exceptions > /dev/null \
        <<< 'Acquire::https::local_repo.local_host.com::Verify-Peer "false";'
```

Note that the latter two options may require you to also set `SHELL /bin/bash` since `<<<` is a bash-ism not available in plain `sh`.